# C semaphore producer-consumer critical section

Tags: c, semaphore, producer-consumer, critical-section

Here is my understanding of semaphores:

If you have a semaphore here called sem1 and you have a critical section after it. Then once the code after the semaphore gets entered it will execute fully. So if you have the following pseudocode:

```
sem_wait(sem1)
  //#CRITICAL SECTION
  //code 1 
  //code 2
sem_post(sem1)
```

Then both lines code 1, code 2 will be executed without any halting correct? The same would be true even if there are 500 lines of code in the critical section, correct?

Now, the reason why I ask this is because of a really weird bug I have encountered from the following code:

```
while (1) {
      int binary;
      sem_wait(&shared_mem->bufferUnderflow);
        printf("we passed the underflow\n");
        sem_wait(&shared_mem->binary);
          sem_getvalue(&shared_mem->binary, &binary);
          printf("currentIndex is %d",shared_mem->frontBuffer);
          printf("we passed the binary:%d\n",binary);
          //*****HERE******
            printf("currentIndex is %d",shared_mem->frontBuffer);
            //if we pass here then we can safely take the Job
            Job currentJob = shared_mem->jobs[shared_mem->frontBuffer];
            printf("we took a job");
            int currentIndex = shared_mem->frontBuffer;
            printf("we took currentIndex");
            //change the indeces now that we have popped the latest one
            shared_mem->frontBuffer = (shared_mem->frontBuffer + 1) % sizeBuffer;
            printf("we changed the index");
            //shared_mem->freeIndex = (shared_mem->freeIndex + 1) % sizeBuffer;
        sem_post(&shared_mem->binary);
    sem_post(&shared_mem->bufferOverflow);
    //consume the Job
    printf("Printer starts printing %d pages from Buffer[%d]", (currentJob).pages,currentIndex);
    sleep(currentJob.duration);

}
return 0;
}
```

Here, I would assume that when the line "we passed the binary:0" gets printed then all the code after this should be executed.
It is not the case though. Any code after 
    //*****HERE******
does not get executed immediately. Its only when I insert something else into the buffer by the producer that the rest of the critical section gets executed.

Sorry for the long post. If anyone has any hints at all as to what could be causing this, please let me know.
Any help at all is appreciated!

Comment: Are you using existing semaphore libraries, or are you writing your own?

Comment: What is the default semaphore count value? Why not just mutexes (ie: semaphores with `count=1`)?

Comment: @callyalater Good point. If OP wrapped his/her own semaphore calls, they may not be atomic.

Comment: In your inner `sem_wait/sem_post` pair you use the same argument (`shared_mem->binary`) but in the outer one the arguments are different `bufferUnderflow` vs `bufferOverflow` - is that right?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments 

@callyalater using POSIX Semaphores

Comment: @Dogbert binary has default count = 1, essentially a mutex

Comment: @500-InternalServerError yep that's correct I believe, first one makes it so I only enter when there is something in the buffer. I then increment the bufferOverflow so that I know that there is now a free space in the buffer.

Comment: To answer one of your questions, the code between sem_wait and sem_post is not necessarily executed without interruption. That's why you use a semaphore (or mutex) – to keep other threads/processes from interfering with what you're trying to do.

Comment: Typically, and generally, you need three semaphores to manage a bounded queue, or two semaphores and a mutex, so it does not seem unreasonable to use 'bufferUnderflow', 'bufferOverflow' and 'binary' to manage the queue.

Comment: Note - you should flush out the printf()'s else you may come to an erroneous conclusion re. happens before/after.

Comment: @Andy Schweig I essentially have a mutex though, just called it "binary" here though.

Comment: " it will execute fully" no, it may be interrupted by other threads. It's just guaranteed that no other thread (if a binary semaphore) will enter the critical section.

Comment: Are you able to reduce the problem to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can copy/paste/build your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note - you should flush out the printf()'s else you may come to an erroneous conclusion re. happens before/after.